# Phonegap Build External Hosts

Tags: android, cordova

My real problem is that I need to get youtube videos to play from my app but I can't seem to get it to work... all my research has brought me to this point (hence why I am asking):

As documented [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/76) in order to allow external content to open in an iFrame with phonegap you need to modify phonegap.plist.

I've been using their "Build" service which allows you to just add a .zip file and it complies everything for you (spitting out complied code in different formats)

Is there a way to edit phonegap.plist and still use the "Build" service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to edit phonegap.plist and still use the "Build" service?

No, although you can configure some of the items that end up in the phonegap.plist through a config.xml (see [docs](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)), the ExternalHosts is not one of the current configurable options.

Also see this related discussion on their [feedback forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/any_way_to_include_phonegap_plist_using_online_build_method).

Comment: Not entirely true - you can use [the access tag](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) to create whitelisting on your PhoneGap Build application